# HTTPClient 4.x - first http request significantly slower

Tags: java, benchmarking, apache-httpclient-4.x

I changed my implementation using a newer version of Apache HTTP Client (3.x before, now 4.x)
My problem is, that the first HTTP request of a series of 4 different GET requests takes significantly
longer than the following ones. This problem is reproducable, if a pause of 60 seconds is done between each request-series. below there are my results of a simple benchmark. server code stays the same and also the requests are always the same. 
I think the problem is something inside the client is destroyed after not used and re-created 
It would be help if somebody has any idea what I could configure to avoid this poor performance.

**Apache HTTP Client 3.x**

```
REQUEST A  duration in ms >>    25
REQUEST B  duration in ms >>    20
REQUEST C  duration in ms >>    15
REQUEST D  duration in ms >>    15
        ----->>> 60 sec pause
REQUEST A  duration in ms >>    20
REQUEST B  duration in ms >>    15
REQUEST C  duration in ms >>    15
REQUEST D  duration in ms >>    15
```

**Apache HTTP Client 4.2.6**

```
REQUEST A  duration in ms >>    4659
REQUEST B  duration in ms >>    25
REQUEST C  duration in ms >>    20
REQUEST D  duration in ms >>    20
        ----->>> 60 sec pause   
REQUEST A  duration in ms >>    4510
REQUEST B  duration in ms >>    20
REQUEST C  duration in ms >>    15
REQUEST D  duration in ms >>    10
```

Thank you very much in advance

Shane

Comment: Can you share the URL you use and your code along with the exact version number for HTTP client ?

Comment: Are you creating HttpClient instance(s) inside the loop?

Comment: i have a same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanking you very much. To be more exact, i am using HTTP Client 4.2.6 inside the Resteasy 3.0.9 framework.
Some example would be this code:

```
ProxyFactory.create(ITestService.class, baseUrl, new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient));
```

The problem was (means it is reproducable) that i was using a deprecated contrutor of the Scheme class fore registering a new scheme to apache "Scheme Registry"

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
```

**WRONG -> using deprecated Scheme constructor**

```
registry.register(new Scheme("http",PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), usedPort));
```

**correct way**

```
registry.register(new Scheme("http",usedPort,PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
```